# In my version of the game "hangman" i am getting an error in a function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "randword.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool hangmachine(char a[],string randi,char v){   //the Problem is in this function

bool retus=0;
for (int cc=0;cc<randi.length();cc++){
if(v==randi[cc]){
retus=1;
char a[cc]=v;     //Error: variable-sized object 'a' may not be initialized.....
}
}
return retus;
}


int main()
{
InitDictionary();
string tixaio=Randomword();
int m = tixaio.length();
int guesses=8;
char guess;
char *charptr= new char[m];


for(int aa=0;aa<m;aa++){
charptr[aa]='-';

}
charptr[m]='\0';

cout << "The word now looks like this: "<<charptr;
cout<< endl;

while (guesses>0){

    cout<<"Give me your guess: ";
    cin>> guess;
    cout<<endl;
    if(hangmachine(charptr,tixaio,guess)){
        cout <<"the string has now become"<<charptr<<endl;
        cout <<"You have "<< guesses<<" remaining guesses"<< endl;

    }

    else{
    guesses-=1;
    cout<<"you made a wrong guess .Now you have "<< guesses<<" remaining tries"<< endl;

    }


}


}
```

The problem seems to be that i am not passing the dynamically allocated array to the function in the right way. I have made comments to the line i am getting this error.But the compiler doesn't give me any error when i call the function in the main() so it must be something wrong in the way i define this function.Any help would be appreciated.

Sometimes i feel so stupid......Sorry for not being carefull enough.

Comment: homework? if so, please tag as such.

Comment: what kind of title is this? is it relevant that it's a hangman game? no. "i getting an error" - you get a compilation error. but what is the error?

Comment: Guys problem solved .You can see the error in the code as a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
char a[cc]=v;
```

is a variable declaration, which doesn't even compile, as the array size should be fixed at compilation time, that is, it has to be either a number or a const integer. It isn't, so you gcc tries to create a variable length array, but then you try to initialize it which will fail.

You just want to set a value in the array:

```
a[cc]=v;
```

Answer (score 3):

change this `char a[cc]=v;` to `a[cc] = v;`

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[cc]=v;
```

**Variable length arrays(VLA)** are not supported by the C++ standard.
An compiler extension in gcc supports them but that is non portable.

The compiler sees above statement as an attempt to declare an array with variable number of arguments, and hence it gives an error.

What you are trying to do is **Assign** an value to an array element.

it should be:

```
a[cc] = v;
```

Comment: variable length auto arrays are valid in C99

Comment: @phoxis: Q is tagged c++ and not c.